# Django cannot filter on timestamp field when the T charcter is found

Tags: django-rest-framework

I Have many of objects like this

```
 {
        "timestamp": "2020-05-12T18:06:50+08:00",
        "name": "w1w1w",
        "type": {
            "id": 19,
            "eventname": "test1433",
            "priority": 3
        }
    },
```

when i'm trying to filter like this

```
        queryset = queryset.filter(timestamp__range=["2020-05-05T18:06:50+08:00", "2020-05-12T18:06:50+08:00"])
```

the filter not work
but when i write this:

```
        queryset = queryset.filter(timestamp__range=["2020-04-01", "2020-05-15"])
```

the filter work correctly

Comment: What type is the `timestamp` field defined as in the model?

Comment: It's DatetimeField

Answer (score 0):

The default for [DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS) do not contain the "T" version format. You could add it yourself.

See:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#datetimefield